# How do I represent two entities having the same relationship with another entit

Tags: sql

I want to make it so that a Prime user can only apply for up to 5 jobs, and a Gold user can apply to unlimited jobs. So both users are "Job applicants" and the "Applies for" relationship represents that.

When I convert "Applies for" into a relation, it should be something like

Job applications (userID(PRIMARY KEY), jobName)
plus a few other attributes I might add.

where jobName is an attribute of Job Listing, being a foreign key of it.

How do I represent this? Or do I need to have 2 identical "applies for" relationships, one for each type of user?

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

You only have one type of "applies for" relationship.

You have a business rule based on the type of users.  In most databases, you would implement the business rule using triggers when someone applies for a job.  If a prime user is applying for their 6th job, then the trigger would generate an error.

Comment: but what would the ER model of that look like? I want the prime user to have a "many to 5" relationship with job listing, and gold user to have "many to many"

Comment: @AndrewKor . . . It is a 1-many or 0-many relationship.  ER diagrams cannot directly represent all possible business rules.